# How should I do this in command prompt?

Tags: python, cmd, command-line, directory, command

I made a file organizer code in python that uses command prompt and I got it to work by moving it into my C:/Users/Username folder and copying my downloads folder (which is what I want to sort) but when I type in

```
C:\python file_organizer.py Downloads
```

It says there is no such file called file_organizer.py. But now when I move the program into C:\ it says it cant find Downloads. This is my first time using command prompt does anyone have any tips.

Comment: The command line needs to know where your Python program is. If you don't specify a full path, and it isn't in the current directory, then it tries the folders named in the `%PATH%` environment variable. Your program also needs to know where `Downloads` is. Unless you have written your program to search for it according to the `%PATH%` environment variable, it will also need a full path. Without that it will expect to find the folder in the current working directory: the one that appears before `>` at the command prompt. Probably the simplest way out is a `cd` command.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using `Downloads` you can run command having complete path to the `Downloads` folder like below

`C:\python file_organizer.py C:/Users/Username/Downloads`

**NOTE:** Replace `Username` with the correct username as per your device where you are trying to run this command.

Comment: Yeah I will try but when I copy address to "Downloads" it just says Downloads this and for the Username that was just trying to maintain security

Answer (score 0):

You should add the full path to Downloads

C:\ python file_organizer.py C:\FullPathToDownloads\Downloads

Comment: What is the full path to downloads though when I copy address it is just downloads

Comment: Windows 10 has this horrible feature that hides full paths. Open the command prompt and type >cd "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads", that will hopefully show you the full path to use.